# Cast warning when initialising variable within if

Tags: c, if-statement, gcc-warning

Using flags, -pedantic -Wall -ansi, I have noticed when I 
intialise a variable `f1=fopen(argv[1],"r");` and then pass the variable
`f1` into an `if` statement, it does so without error.

However when I intialise the variable within an if statement it will throw a warning:

`warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]`

I have my ideas, but am unsure why this is.

```
FILE *f1;
FILE *f2;
f1=fopen(argv[1],"r");

if(f1==NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr,"unable to open file - %s\n",f1);
}
if(f2=fopen("output.txt","w")==NULL) /*throws warning*/
{
     fprintf(stderr,"unable to open file - %s\n",f2);
}
```

*I have tested both f1 and f2 to be initialised in both ways and get the same response for both.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(f2=fopen("output.txt","w")==NULL)
```

`==` has higher precedence than `=`, so you're actually storing a boolean (which is an `int` in C90) in a pointer. Add some parentheses :

```
if((f2 = fopen("output.txt","w")) == NULL)
```

Comment: I'd suggest "storing an `int` in a pointer". `==` evaluates to an `int`, not to a `_Bool`. E.g. gcc gives an error with the flags above for a `_Bool`-to-pointer conversion without a cast, but only a warning for an `int`-to-pointer conversion as in the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (f2 = fopen("output.txt","w") == NULL)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (f2 = (fopen("output.txt","w") == NULL))
```

It's assigning `f2` with either `1` or `0` depending on whether `fopen("output.txt","w")` is equal to `NULL`.

What you need is:

```
if ((f2 = fopen("output.txt","w")) == NULL)
```